# Real solution of equation cantaining exponential and cosine function

Tags: calculus

> If $\ln(2\pi)<\log_{2}(2+\sqrt{3}),$ Then number of real roots of the equation $4\cos(e^x)=2^x+2^{-x}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$f(x)=2^x+2^{-x}-4\cos(e^x)$$

Then $$f'(x) = 2^{x}\ln(2)-2^{-x}\ln(2)+4\sin(e^x)\cdot e^x$$

and $$f''(x)=2^{x}(\ln(2))^2+2^{-x}(\ln(2))^2+4\sin(e^x)e^x+4\cos(e^x)e^x$$

Now how can i solve after that, Help required, Thanks

Comment: Should that say *find* the number of real roots?

Comment: i think there are three real solutions